# Nokogiri put tags with separation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

**I'd like to message separate with :**

```
teste = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")
    Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with( teste ){ |x|  
        x.exemplo "teste xml"
    }
    puts teste.to_xml
```

**Message printing**

```
<exemplo>teste xml</exemplo>
```

**Message you want**

```
<ns3:exemplo>teste</ns3:exemplo>
```

Comment: try `puts teste.to_text`

Comment: I'do like to message you want: <ns3:exemplo>teste</ns3:exemplo>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
teste = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")

Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(teste) do |x|
  x.root('xmlns:ns3' => 'Example namespace') do
    x['ns3'].example "Example Test"
  end
end
puts teste.to_xml
```

Keep in mind that you must define the namespace before you can use. Then you use `Nokogiri::XML::Builder#[]` to define a namespace and after that it's normal Nokogiri syntax.